# How to pass node version to React environment variable?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables

I tried several variations but doesn't work:

```
"start:app": "cross-env REACT_APP_APPENV=local REACT_APP_NODE_VERSION=`node -v` react-scripts start

"start:app": "cross-env REACT_APP_APPENV=local REACT_APP_NODE_VERSION=`node --version` react-scripts start

"start:app": "cross-env REACT_APP_APPENV=local REACT_APP_NODE_VERSION=`node -v` react-scripts start
"start:app": "cross-env REACT_APP_APPENV=local REACT_APP_NODE_VERSION='node --v' react-scripts start
```

But all fail with error similar to this trace:

```
'-v' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn -v ENOENT
```

This is for the local setup, wherein I run `npm run start:app`

**NOTE:** In the Jenkins build server, I am able to this just fine:

```
export REACT_APP_NODE_VERSION=`node --version`
npm ci
npm run build
```

Anyone ever done this before for **local setup**?

Comment: Are you on a unix-based system? The backticks for execution are a sh/bash-based thing, so that won't work on a Windows-based machine. I'd check if the backticks are executed correctly (on a unix-based system npm defaults to using /bin/sh for the scripts) by making a new script in the package.json with just `"test": "echo \`node -v\`"` or `"test": "echo \"$(node -v)\""`